# PCs in the same network can not communicate

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-vista, router, home-networking

I have 2 PCs.
1 Windows 7/64 bit.
1 Windows Vista.

Both are connected to the same router accessing the public network.
Both can access the Internet.

Problem:
None of the PCs can ping each other.
What am I missing here? Shouldn't it be possible for 1 PC to ping the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have windows firewall on both of them. You need to explicitly allow ICMP echo requests, as the firewall does not by default.

You need to go to Windows Firewall in Control Panel then click on advanced settings in the left pane. The option that needs to be allowed is "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" You might as well enable it for IPv6 while you are in there as well. Picture of the option in Windows 7 (probably similar for vista):

[image]

Comment: That was it.BTW isn't this risky when the PCs are connected to public network?

Comment: Not really it's just ICMP traffic, basically worst case scenario is someone can find your host as active with an IP scan. We didn't open any ports or anything that would allow intruders access.

Comment: Kyle:Hm....Could you please check out this one? http://superuser.com/questions/347493/open-a-port-safely-in-firewall-for-a-pc-connected-to-internet

Answer (score 1):

> ... "the public network."

1. Change your network from 'public' to 'private' via a single click within the Network/Share Center on each PC.

That alone will do it; however. consider ditching Windows Firewall for an excellent third-party firewall (a few free ones do exist that are of such quality - even though I'm dying to recommend 2 to you. do your own research - always do your own research).  If you stick with Windows Firewall, and insist on keeping your network 'public', then definitely follow Kyle's instructions if you actually do mean ping as in *ping* or ping as in a word for something else you associate with pinging.